# Conditional does not seem to be working in Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

My goal is to, upon clicking a button, redirect from my practice_test_view to my main controller's function setupTask, passing in the variable $test_id.  This part seems to work.  However, once the function is called, no matter what the test_id variable is, it seems to be running through the main else clause, because it always calls the getKey function from my model, even when it should not.  This causes the following errors to appear in the browser tools:

```
<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined variable: test_name</p>
<p>Filename: models/main_model.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 45</p>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  file_get_contents(files/_key.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory</p>
<p>Filename: models/main_model.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 45</p>
```

practice_test_view (relevant portion):

```
<div style='position: relative; width: 595px; margin: 20px auto;'>
    <input style='text-align:center; width:220px;' type="button" id='rounded' value="Click here to begin test" onClick="location.href='<?php echo site_url("main/setupTask/". "/" . "$test_id"); ?>'";>
</div>
```

my Main Controller function:

```
public function setupTask($test_id){

    $this->load->model('Main_model');

    if($test_id == 5 || $test_id == 6){
        $random_array = $this->Main_model->createRandomArray();

        shuffle($random_array);

        if($test_id == 6){
            $test_key = $this->Main_model->createSpatialKey($random_array);
            $data['test_key'] = $test_key;
            $data['test_id'] = $test_id;
        }
        else{
            $data['test_key'] = $random_array;
            $data['test_id'] = $test_id;
        }
        $this->load->view('test_view', $data);
    }
    else{
        $json_key = $this->Main_model->getKey($test_id);
        $json_key = json_decode($json_key, true);
        shuffle($json_key);

        $data['test_key'] = $json_key;
        $data['test_id'] = $test_id;

        $this->load->view('test_view', $data);
    }
}
```

my Main Model:

```
class Main_model extends CI_Model{
    public function getKey($test_id){

        switch($test_id){
          case 1:
            $test_name = "example";
            break;
          case 2:
            $test_name = "example";
            break;
          case 3:
            $test_name = "example";
            break;
        }

        $image_array = file_get_contents('files/' . $test_name . '_key.json');

        return $image_array;
     }

    public function createRandomArray(){
      $verbal_array = array();

      for($i=0; $i<60; $i++){
        $random = mt_rand(1,4);
        $random_array[$i] = $random;
      }

      return $random_array;
    }

  public function createSpatialKey($random_array){

    $test = array();
    $image_array = file_get_contents('files/spatial_working_memory_key.json');

    $image_array = json_decode($image_array, true);

    foreach($random_array as $question){
      $q = $question - 1;
      array_push($test, $image_array[$q]);
    } 

    return $test;
  }
}
```

In the switch statement in the model, I've replaced the actual test names with 'example' and have shortened it because the rest of the statement is organized just like the partial shown.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does your view look like where you are linking to setupTask?

Comment: Edited the post to show the relevant parts of the view.

Comment: If you set `$test_id = 5` or `$test_id = 6` at the start of the function, does it work properly?

Comment: @Cro, oddly enough, based on the console logs, the test_key and test_id get set appropriately when I set $test_id to 5 or 6, however I still get the same error.  It still seems to call the getKey function in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view change

```
<?php echo site_url("main/setupTask/". "/" . "$test_id"); ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo base_url("main/setupTask/". $test_id); ?>
```

Make the following changes to your getKey() function

```
public function getKey($test_id){

    switch($test_id){
      case 1:
        $test_name = "example";
        break;
      case 2:
        $test_name = "example";
        break;
      case 3:
        $test_name = "example";
        break;
      default:
        $test_name = '';
        break;
    }

    if($test_name !== ''){

        $image_array = file_get_contents('files/' . $test_name . '_key.json');

        return $image_array;

    } else {

        return FALSE;

    }

 }
```

Comment: I did that, and the same error is occurring.  I had that part working, I think I just incorrectly modified it when I copy and pasted the code over.  Either way, the same issue is arising.

Comment: Try adding this at the top of setupTask(): log_message('DEBUG', $test_id); You will want to insure logging is enabled in your /config/config.php file around line 179. This will allow you to see the actual value that is being passed into the function in the application log.

Comment: It does show that, in this case, a 1 was passed, which was expected.

Comment: Even if I place the debug statement in the model, in the getKey function, which is where the error seems to be occurring, I still see that the correct value gets passed to it.

Comment: If you pass a 5 or a 6 are you able to hit your if block? In the original comment you had stated that you were always hitting the else block regardless of what was passed.

Comment: I'm sorry for misstating it.  What I meant was that it seems to always hit the else block regardless of whether or not it goes into the if block.  If I pass a 5 or 6, it does go into the if block, and seems to set all the values correctly, but it still calls the getKey function of my Main_model as shown by the error message.  Sorry for the confusing explanation.

Comment: Try adding a default block to your switch statement and see if that takes care of the undefined variable error.

Comment: I made the changes, but still the same error.  I'm beginning to think there is something more fundamentally wrong with how I have the code structured that is causing this.